# How do I copy sibling to sibling in multiple different parents at the same time using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple parents, more than 2, but this is just example, and I would like to copy from all the base prices to all the own prices with a click of one button.

```
<button type="button" id="copybtn" class="btn">Copy</button>

<p class="baseownwrap">
    <label>thing1</label>
    <span class="baseprice">1</span>
    <input class="ownprice" type="text" value="" name="price[]">
</p>

<p class="baseownwrap">
    <label>thing2</label>
    <span class="baseprice">2</span>
    <input class="ownprice" type="text" value="" name="price[]">
</p>

//something like this, but this doesn't work
$('#copybtn').click(function(){
    $('.ownprice').val($(this).siblings('.baseprice').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each element with class `.ownprice` and copy the value from the element with class `.baseprice`:

```js
$('#copybtn').click(function() {
  $(".ownprice").each(function() {
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).prev().text(), 10));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="copybtn" class="btn">Copy</button>

<p class="baseownwrap">
  <label>thing1</label>
  <span class="baseprice">1</span>
  <input class="ownprice" type="text" value="" name="price[]">
</p>

<p class="baseownwrap">
  <label>thing2</label>
  <span class="baseprice">2</span>
  <input class="ownprice" type="text" value="" name="price[]">
</p>
```

**References:**

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: what's the number 10 for?

Comment: To specify the radix.[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @leoarce Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each parent using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method, then get the value of children `baseprice` and add it to `.ownprice`.

```
$('#copybtn').click(function() {
    $(".baseownwrap").each( function(){
        bestPriceValue = $('.baseprice', this).text();
        $('.ownprice', this).val(bestPriceValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: this works too if not going with parseint method. both are helpful, thanks.